# Why doesn't Python's os.exec* functions pass any arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to replace the current process with a new process using the same Python interpreter, but with a new script. I have tried using [`os.execl`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execl), which seemed like the most intuitive approach:

```
print(sys.executable, script_path, *args)
os.execl(sys.executable, script_path, *args)
```

The result is that this is printed to the screen (from the `print` function):

```
/home/tomas/.pyenv/versions/3.4.1/bin/python script.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

And the Python interactive interpreter is launched. Entering this into the interpreter:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.argv)
['']
```

Shows that Python received no arguments.

If I copy the output of the `print` function and enter it into my terminal, it works as expected. I have also tried using `execv` and `execlp` with identical results.

---

Why doesn't the `execl` call pass the arguments to the Python executable?

Answer (score 2):

The arg0, arg1, arg2, ... (arguments after the `sys.executable`) are passed to subprogram as `argv`. If you pass `script_path` as a the first argument the subprogram will interpret `script_path` as argv[0] instead of `sys.executable`.

Replace the `execl` line as following will solve your problem:

```
os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, script_path, *args)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: You are right, that worked. It doesn't quite make sense to me though. I have two followup questions I'd be delighted if you could add to your answer. #1: Are there any cases where one would *not* add the executable as the first item in argv? If not, why isn't it added implicitly? #2: Why did the Python interpreter find **no** arguments in my example? I get that it interpreted `script_path` as `argv[0]`, but that doesn't explain why `sys.argv` was `['']` and not `["script.py", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]`.

Comment: @Hubro, #1, Sometimes, you may don't want to expose the real path of the executable. (`ps aux` or `ps -efl` will show the name passed instead of real path)

Comment: @Hubro, #2, `sys.argv` is different from `argv` in C. Python consumes the first item. `argv[0]`.

Comment: @Hubro, #2, According to python man page: ... If  available,  the script name and additional arguments thereafter are passed to the script in the Python variable sys.argv, which is  a  list of  strings (you must first import sys to be able to access it).  If no script name is given, sys.argv[0] is an empty string; ....